# Filtering Firebase Database on button click returns single Recycle View listItem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want ListView to show only that data which has company name equal to the one entered in EditText on Search Button Click :

[image: Screenshot OF Edit Text & Search Button]

Button Click Event -

```
Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText objCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterEdit);
        mMessagesDatabaseReference.orderByChild("company").equalTo(objCompany.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    for(DataSnapshot d1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        for(DataSnapshot d2 : d1.child("company").getChildren()) {
                            postAdapterObject.clear();
                            // Get the value from the DataSnapshot and add it to the item list
                            post itemObject = d1.getValue(post.class);
                            //this is where data from database is entered into a list of objects
                            postAdapterObject.add(itemObject);
                            postAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Filtered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    postAdapterObject.clear();
                    postAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                postAdapterObject.clear();
                postAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Data Found! Try with some other data entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: Firebase Database Image -]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looping one level too deep in your JSON. This is a lot simpler, and should be close to what you need:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    postAdapterObject.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot d1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        post itemObject = d1.getValue(post.class);
        postAdapterObject.add(itemObject);
    }
    postAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (postAdapterObject.size() > 0) { // TODO: write this condition
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Filtered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

You may need to fix the check in `if (postAdapterObject.size() > 0) {`, since it depends on the type of `postAdapterObject`.